# Meaning of "Identify a set with another set" in group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, intuition

There is a exercise problem that asks "Identify a set with another set ". I don't understand what I should do. Do I need to establish a bijection between them? Thanks

**EDIT-I:** Actual question: G is a group. S is a set. G acts on S. For $x\in S$, $G.s:=\{g.s|g\in G\}$ is a orbit. $G_s:=\{g\in G|g(s)=s\}$ is an isotropy group. Now I need to identify $G.s$ with the quotient $G/G_s:=\{gG_s|g\in G\}$ by the action of $G_s$ on the right.

I found a following bijection: $$\alpha: G/G_s \to G.s, \ gG_s \mapsto g.s$$

Is this enough?

Comment: It would likely help if you gave the actual question.

Comment: Please check now!

Comment: It's still incomplete. You should write that $G$ acts on $S$. Otherwise orbit and isotropy are ill-defined.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. But I know that such an action is there. Thanks.

Comment: You have the right bijection, but you need to include a proof that it really is a bijection.

Comment: I have the proof. I only wanted to understand the meaning of "identify with".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title doesn't fit to the question. $G/G_s$ is not a group. It is a left $G$-set. Also the orbit $Gs$ is a left $G$-set. And the actual statement is that these two left $G$-sets are isomorphic. Your isomorphism is correct.

Comment: I have tried to make the edit. Please edit to make it clearer, in case it's not!